# 3rd party ios app automation with Appium on real device

Tags: appium, appium-ios

Is it possible to automate 3rd party iOS apps with Appium on real device(eg YouTube) ?
I know I need to have apple developer account to be able to automate real iOS devices.

There are similar questions on this topic but those I found are more than 4 years old and I would like to know if it's possible in 2022.
Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you intend to automate an App Store app, yes, it's possible. Just that you would need to install the app manually on your device. Appium won't be able to install the app automatically from the App Store.

Once the app is installed, you can instruct Appium to launch it and perform the UI actions.

But do know that popular apps like YouTube, Facebook, etc. may detect and block the bots like Appium from logging into the account programmatically.